# retool - javascript filtering doesnt work in event handlers

Tags: javascript, filter, retool

can someone help me with problem described here:
https://community.retool.com/t/i-need-ur-help-with-api-filtering/10167

Filtering doesnt work, and retool community is too small, there is no help.

Thanks.

Comment: The linked page does not exist (or is private). It is preferred to not link to external sites anyway as their availability is not under control of StackOverflow, so please include all the relevant information in your question here.  That being said, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what problem you have with filter in the Retool javascript. I can confirm that it does indeed work. You need to ensure that you are calling filter on the array, and not the query object.

So in retool it is usually:

```
queryResult.data.filter()
```

not

```
queryResult.filter()
```